i want to know how to calculate any ip adress for a given nth subnet

your company requested and received the network address 197.20.2.0. For reasons related to its organization, you want to have 24 usable subnetworks
a. what will be the value of the subnet mask?
b. give the broadcast address of the 20th usable subnetwork
c. give the ip address of the 4th host of the 15th subnet?


This two-part answer explains it all.

By the way, all "education, certification, or homework" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

... and class-based VLSM subnetting was obsoleted more than 30 years ago. It's all CIDR since.
